# How to use relational operators with a random number generator (c)

Tags: c, random

I am trying to make a program that generates a random number (this part works), and then prints something depending on whether the number is greater or less than 555,555,555. While the correct thing prints if the number is over 555,555,555, nothing at all prints when the number is below 555,555,555.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    int rand();
    
    time_t secondsFromEpoch = time(NULL);
    srand(secondsFromEpoch);
    printf("%d\n", rand());
    
    if (rand() > 555555555) {
        printf("hello");
    }
    else if (rand() < 555555555) {
        printf("goodbye");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are calling `rand()` three times and getting three likely different random numbers. Call it once, save the result in a variable, and use that variable to print and examine the number.

Comment: You also don't need to provide your own prototype for `rand()`. It's in`<stdlib.h>`.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `rand` multiple times.  Each time you call it, it returns a different number.

Save the random number in a variable and use that.

```
int r = rand();
printf("%d\n", r);

if (r > 555555555) {
    printf("hello");
}
else if (r < 555555555) {
    printf("goodbye");
}
```